# Replacing nested loops in Python using NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

So I have these 6 nested loops, and their purpose is only to multiply and add arrays `X` and `Y` over different indices to get array `Z`.

```py
import numpy as np

dim_a = 5
dim_b = 9
Z = np.zeros((dim_a,dim_b,dim_b,dim_a))
X = np.arange(2025).reshape(dim_a,dim_b,dim_b,dim_a)
Y = np.arange(2025).reshape(dim_a,dim_b,dim_b,dim_a)

for i in range(0, dim_a):
    for j in range(0,dim_a):
        for a in range(0, dim_b):
            for b in range(0, dim_b):
                for m in range(0,dim_a):
                    for e in range(0,dim_b):
                        Z[i,a,b,j] += X[m,e,b,j] * Y[m,e,a,i] * 2
```

Is there a way to write it using just a few lines of code using NumPy? The computational effort of these nested loops is enormous. I have a feeling that NumPy can optimize it significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do with [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
Z[i,a,b,j] += X[m,e,b,j] * Y[m,e,a,i] * 2
```

translates to

```
Z = np.einsum('mebj,meai->iabj', X,Y) * 2
```

Comment: This is amazing! I checked the computational times:

`6 nested loops: 0.14539456367492676`
`np.einsum: 0.000209808349609375`

Comment: Also the same as ```np.einsum('mebj,meai,...->iabj', X, Y, 2)```. Although, not sure if this is any faster.